# iPhone has denied the launch request - On provision profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, udid, mobileprovision

A company that I am developing a project for, gave me a `.mobileprovision` file and a `.p12` certificate to add APNS to their project. As long as I've added their provision profile to my project in XCode, XCode keeps saying "iPhone has denied the launch request." when I try to build project on my physical device.

I've tried deleting certificate Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority, and adding another user account to mac but non of them worked. Only when I disabled Debug executable, the app launched successfully, but it's not a solution because I need to debug the app.

Should I tell them to add my device UDID to their account's devices on developer.apple.com?

Comment: It was a "launch request", not "lunch request", right?

Comment: ask for team member account

Answer (score 0):

You've been given an Adhoc distribution provisioning profile, which don't allow the debugger to attach (they're missing the `get-task-allow` entitlement), as they're for use when you distribute your app for testing, not local development.

If you need to debug, they'll have to supply you with a development p12 certificate and a matching provisioning profile.

Comment: thank you for answer... they have sent me both p12 file and provision file. with these two files can I say that the account that I am using is a development account? not a distribution one?

Comment: There's not a surefire way to tell unless their names give it away, but if you open the provisioning profile in a text editor, for a distribution profile there should be only one item under the `DeveloperCertificates` key, and the `get-task-allow` entitlement should be false: https://i.imgur.com/UMH0KYz.png

Answer (score 0):

You are trying with `Development Profile` vs `Distribution Profile`?

- `Distribution Profile`:

With `AdHoc Distribution profile`, you can't debug any app it should be used for distribution only.

- `Development Profile`:

If you didn't add your device `UDID` to the `provisioning profile`, you can try to do that and re-generate the `provisioning profile` and download it.

In `Keychain Access`, you will get to know which profile you received from the team,

[image: Keychain]

Comment: thank you. but how can I understand if my profile is Development or Distribution?

Comment: From `Keychain Access` you should get to know

Answer (score 0):

> gave me a ".mobileprovision" file and a ".p12" certificate

That seems like a red herring. I would suggest ignoring both of those.  If they want you to work on their app, they simply make you a team member. Done! Your own dev center membership is then sufficient to debug on device.